# Remove HTTP server and X-Powered-By headers

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, http-headers, azure-web-app-service

My app is deployed on azure app service.  Response of my server includes the following HTTP headers

```
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Which i would like permanently exclude from my responses.

The problem is the following. I tried three things

1. Changes in web.config file

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <remove name="Server" />
        <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" />
    </security>
   </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```

In my localhost i run my app and make request i do not get  aforementioned headers, but when i deploy it on azure i get the headers again.

2. Change Startup.cs file

   ```
          app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
                context.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Powered-By");
                await next();
            });
   ```

This produce the same result  in localhost ok but when deploy get the same headers.

3. Write middleware

   ```
   public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
   {
       context.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
       context.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Powered-By");

       await _next(context);
   }

       app.UseMiddleware<HttpMiddleware>();
       app.UseAuthentication();
       app.UseMiddleware<RequestLoggingMiddleware>();
   ```

This is also produce the same result, in localhost ok but  when deploy to the azure get the same headers.
I am not the azure/cloud expert but maybe there is something that need to be changed on azure?

Comment: Seems in line with azure's direct guidance..  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/removing-standard-server-headers-on-windows-azure-web-sites/ - are you sure it's deployed accurately?

Comment: Attempting to remove CORS headers will probably cause issues in the end..

Comment: @NeoXX any update? Does my reply help you?

Answer (score 4):

According to your description, I suggest you could try below way to remove the `X-Powered-By: ASP.NET`.

If you host the application on linux, you could try to modify the UseKestrel setting in Program.CS:

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseKestrel(option => option.AddServerHeader = false);
                
            });
```

Result:

[image]

If you host the application on windows, you should modify the web.config to remove the header.

Like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <!-- To customize the asp.net core module uncomment and edit the following section. 
  For more info see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=838655 -->

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>


</configuration>
```

Result:

[image]